# Is there any other possibility: if $\int f(x) dx =f(x)$ find $\int \left( f(x)\right)^2 dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int f(x) dx =f(x)$$
>   Then 
>   $$\int \left( f(x)\right)^2 dx$$ is equal to

I know that $e^x$ will satisfy this . Is there any other function that will satisfy this or $e^x$ is the only one which will satisfy this .

Comment: what is the "then" about?

Comment: I tried to change the title to reflect the question (I think) - if you were asking something else, then edit the title, but keep it specific

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to $f'=f$ is $f(x)=Ce^x$ for any constant $C$.

Since $f(x)^2=C^2e^{2x}$, we get
$$
\int f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12f(x)^2+C_2
$$

---

**Nature of the General Solution**

If $f'=f$, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f)=1$. Therefore,
$$
\log(f(x))=x+\log(C)
$$
Thus, if $f'=f$, then
$$
f(x)=Ce^x
$$

Comment: I know this ,I want to know , Is there any other function than $e^x$ that will satisfy it.

Comment: Since the **general** solution is $Ce^x$ those are the **only** functions.